# ActiveRecord Arel vs SQL and best practices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

Today I learned about how to use Arel to construct SQL queries that would require SQL fragments with standard ActiveRecord. Until now, all Rails apps I've seen have (at best) scopes which wrap raw SQL, like these:

```
# in class Post
scope :select_comment_count, -> {
  join_comments.select('COUNT(comments.id)')
}
scope :join_comments, -> {
  joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN comments ON comments.post_id = posts.id AND comments.is_most_recent_edit = '1'")
}
```

Which can both be rewritten in Arel using no SQL.

My first question is, what are the concrete advantages and disadvantages of using Arel over SQL fragments, and why does is seem as though every app and every RoR developer ignores Arel?

Also, my Arel seems to be really messy by default, partly because my Arel has to have knowledge of my foreign key names:

```
scope :select_comment_count, -> {
  comments = Comment.arel_table
  joins_comments.select(comments[:id].count)
}

scope :join_comments, -> {
  posts = Post.arel_table
  comments = Comment.arel_table

  # Bypasses ActiveRecord associations completely.
  # We're using Arel to generate the above SQL
  # Isn't this exactly the same as using Raw SQL, but slower?
  # In some cases we would still lose DB independence,
  # for instance if we did an update_all with a join in MySQL
  # (not allowed in PostgreSQL)

  sql = posts.
    join(comments, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin).
    on(
          (comments[:post_id].eq(posts[:id])). # Here we duplicate the knowledge of how our foreign key names relate to our associations
      .and(comments[:is_most_recent_edit].eq(false))
    ).join_sql

  joins(join_sql)
}
```

Are there any good tools or libraries out there for unifying the ActiveRecord query interface and Arel more, or any good techniques for keeping your Arel simple and beautiful? I'd really like to use Arel, but in a way that harnesses the power of ActiveRecord associations and doesn't feel like a completely separate API or an extra layer of complication above SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, that first query can be written as `comments.count`, surely?

The reason people tend to use SQL more often is quite clear when you look back at the code in your question. The SQL is way simpler and easier to read.

While there are differences in implementations of SQL, it's worth remembering that SQL is a standard, therefore a lot of it will work in many different database servers too.

On the other hand, you might be interested in the [Squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) gem.

Comment: Looks like Squeel is precisely what I'm after! Thankyou very much! The reason I'd define a scope for doing a count is so that I could include it in a more complex query.

Comment: Well, not really. Squeel doesn't define your associations for use within its DSL, so you still have to specify table names in where scopes. Also, Squeel is incapable of dealing with more than one join condition.

Comment: Also, it breaks my eager loading with `includes`